# unique identity or identifier for view in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, view, identity

I've got a view that's a union of two tables that have overlapping keys and I want to uniquely identify the rows for later retrieval. How can I add an identity or identifier column to the view rows so I can retrieve the rows later by that value?

Comment: Can you post the definitions of the tables and views, and perhaps an example based on them of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up using a uniqueIdentifier field defaulted to NewID() and then populated the archive and current tables with GUIDs.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without your table definitions to hand.  However, could you not create an artificial key on the view e.g:

SELECT 'TABLE1' + CAST(KeyColumn AS VARCHAR) AS 'Key'
FROM
TABLE1

UNION

SELECT 'TABLE2' + CAST(KeyColumn AS VARCHAR) AS 'Key'
FROM
TABLE2